# Valor do select não é recebido no PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentando alterar o login de um usuário, ele está enviando o id, user e pass porém não envia o valor que vem da combobox e preenche como vazio no banco.

Segue o código que estou utilizando:

HTML

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION["user"])){
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Princess Model - Área Administrativa</title>
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="../js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
    include_once("header.php");
    
    //Conexão com o Banco de Dados
    include_once("conecta.php");
    
    //Recebendo os Dados Passados Via GET
    $recid=$_GET["id"];
        
    //Buscar os Dados no Banco para Preencher o Formulário
    $dados=mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id='$recid'");
    $niveis=mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT nivel FROM usuarios WHERE id <> '$recid' ORDER BY nivel ASC");
        
    //Separar os Dados com Array
    $item=mysqli_fetch_array($dados);
    
    ?>
    
    <center>
        <h3 style="margin: 2%;">ALTERAÇÃO DE USUÁRIO</h3>
        <form action="editagravauser.php" method="post" class="formulario" style="width: 30%;">
            <input type="hidden" name="fid" value="<?=$item['id']?>">
            <input type="text" name="fuser" required placeholder="Usuário" class="campo" value="<?=$item['user']?>">
            <input type="text" name="fpass" required placeholder="Senha" class="campo" value="<?=$item['pass']?>">
            <select name="fnivel" class="campo" id="nivel">
                <option value="<?=$item['nivel']?>"><?=$item['nivel']?></option>
                <?php
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($niveis)){
                    print("<option value='".$row['nivel']."'>".$row['nivel']."</option>");
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" class="botao" onClick="valor()"> 
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    }else{
        $erro=md5(2);
        header("location: index.php?erro=".$erro);
    }
?>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    //Conexão
    include_once("conecta.php");
    
    //Recebendo os dados
    $recid=$_POST["fid"];
    $recuser=$_POST["fuser"];
    $recpass=$_POST["fpass"];
    $recnivel=$_POST["fnivel"];

    //Atualizar os dados no Banco de Dados
    mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE usuarios SET user='$recuser', pass='$recpass', nivel='$fnivel' WHERE id=$recid");

    //Redirecionar a página para a lista de usuários
    header("location: usuario.php");
?>
```

Comment: Posta o conteúdo do método valor(), usado no onclick do botão submit, talvez esteja aí o problema.

Comment: Na sua query esta assim `, nivel='$fnivel' `, mas a variavel iniciada é `$recnivel=$_POST["fnivel"];`, como isso me parece um erro de digitação estou votando para fechar

Comment: Deu certo! Eu estava enviando a variável $recnivel como $fnivel no update. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Passei muito por isso kkkk